# Thread-safe Date Parser

Tags: java, date, thread-safety

I'm looking for a thread-safe replacement for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). [`parseObject`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html#parseObject(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) on good old [`FastDateFormat`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) isn't implemented and just throws an error. Any ideas? I don't need anything fancy, just thread-safety and the ability to handle this pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If at all possible, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). Its date/time parsers are thread-safe, and it's generally a *much* nicer API than `Date`/`Calendar`.

You *can* use just its parsers and then convert the return values to `Date`, but personally I would recommend using the whole library instead.

Answer (score 8):

As outlined in [this post](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2010/08/dateformat-with-multiple-threads.html) you can either synchronise, use thread locals or Joda-Time.

For example, using ThreadLocals:

```
public class DateFormatTest {

  private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> df
                 = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>(){
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    }
  };

  public Date convert(String source)
                     throws ParseException{
    Date d = df.get().parse(source);
    return d;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 No blocking. Trade memory for thread safety. No external big library for simple case.

Comment: Your answer is a collateral victim of a high reputation bomb.

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

The `java.time` types are [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). The `java.time` API (the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>) has been there since March 2014 as part of Java SE 8 standard library.

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021-06-13";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-13
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8l5t92)

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. You might have noticed that I have not used a parsing type (`DateTimeFormatter`) in the above code because `yyyy-MM-dd` is also the ISO 8601 pattern for a date.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Why not to put the call of `SimpleDateFormat.parseObject()` into your own `synchronized` block?

Answer (score 1):

Found a [solution](http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html).

```
public class ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormat {

 private DateFormat df;

 public ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormat(String format) {
     this.df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
 }

 public synchronized String format(Date date) {
     return df.format(date);
 }

 public synchronized Date parse(String string) throws ParseException {
     return df.parse(string);
 }
}
```

Comment: That may not perform well, but it's easy. Performance will depend on how many threads are really trying to access the formatter at the same time. I would try this (or just wrapping your calls to SimpleDateFormat in a synch block) first to see if it's really an issue.